# Preserving linefeeds etc. in text content of XSL but not in tags itself

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

While building an XSL document I ran into the following problem. I want to preserve linefeeds in the original text, so I set `linefeed-treatment="preserve"`. However, this apparantly also means it preserves linefeeds outside of the text content and in the actual xml elements. An example:

```
String content = "<fo:block white-space-collapse=\"true\" ><fo:inline>this is some </fo:inline><fo:inline font-weight=\"bold\">custom</fo:inline><fo:inline> \ncontent</fo:inline></fo:block>";
```

This is the text I use as input. It's transformed to an xml document in Java. Note the \n right before content indicating a new line. This will result in the following output in the FO document:

```
<fo:block white-space-collapse="true" linefeed-treatment="preserve">
  <fo:inline>this is some</fo:inline>
  <fo:inline font-weight="bold">custom</fo:inline>
  <fo:inline> 
content</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

So it does show the linebreak right before the text content which is fine.

I use Apache FOP to transform this to a PDF file as well as another third party library to convert this into a DocX file. In both cases the content will then show up like this:

> this is some
>   **custom**
>
> content

When I change my XSL manually and make it like this:

```
<fo:block white-space-collapse="true" linefeed-treatment="preserve"><fo:inline>this is some </fo:inline><fo:inline font-weight="bold">custom</fo:inline><fo:inline> 
content</fo:inline></fo:block>
```

Then my output is fine and like I would expect:

> this is some **custom**
>   content

Obviously I don't want these additional linebreaks coming from the elements itself, but I really do want to preserve linefeeds from the text content. Is there a way to do this? Or is there an alternative solution to get my linebreaks sorted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rather crude work-around, until you find something better.

```
<fo:block white-space-collapse="true" linefeed-treatment="preserve"
  ><fo:inline>this is some</fo:inline
  ><fo:inline font-weight="bold">custom</fo:inline
  ><fo:inline> 
content</fo:inline
></fo:block>
```

This way you can at least keep some of your source code format.

Comment: Creative idea, tried this, unfortunately it has the same result as the original, the processor seems to look at linebreaks wherever they are.

Comment: @Bas: I don't think so. The processor would definitely not notice line breaks *within* tags, this is against every definition of how XML works. Maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: You're right, my bad, I was manually editing it in your format in the wrong part of my test document (using the same custom text somewhere else as well)
So yeah, this could work temporarily if I can get my serializer to output the document in this format. It feels like a bit of a hack but at least it's still human-readable :)

Comment: I'll leave this question open for a bit longer but if I can't actually achieve what I want to achieve I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Bas That's a good idea. Leave it open at least a day or so, as this is one of the niche topics around here. My answer is by any means not definitive.

Answer (score 1):

`<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>` in your XSLT should remove all the tag indentation fromyour output.

Comment: I'm not using XSLT though, I'm generating XSL directly and the possible custom input is also XSL. Is there a similar way to do this in XSL itself?

Comment: I suppose I could tell the document serializer to not pretty-print the document so I don't get these issues, but kinda hoping for a solution where the XSL processor just doesn't look at that kind of information.

Comment: @Bas van den Broek Don't put linefeeds where you don't need them then. It's as simple as that. A text node with only whitespace in it is still a text node and if you explicitly tell the FO engine not to ignore it, it won't.

Comment: @biziclop Oh but I'm fine with the engine looking at special characters inside the actual text such as the linebreak right before 'content', that's what I actually want, I just don't get why it would use information from the layout of the XSL document outside of the actual content. Do you have recommendations on how this could work if I just turn preserving off?

Comment: @Bas van den Broek It isn't outside the actual content, it's whitespace within an `<fo:block>`, so as far as the engine is concerned, it is content. You shouldn't have to rely on linefeed characters for formatting and shouldn't use the `linefeed-treatment` attribute at all, but sometimes there's no other option. The drawback of it is that you can't use pretty indentations for your tags, this is the deal you get, there's no way out of it as far as I know.

Comment: So what would the preferred way to do this be if I could control the input? Simply keep adding blocks or inlines for a new line and set their height?